# Delete duplicate rows of a table based on the value of the previous row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a SQL Table as such:

| serial(pk) | name | status | location | time_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'joe' | 'at_home' | 'USA' | 01:30 |
| 2 | 'jane' | 'at_store' | 'USA' | 02:30 |
| 3 | 'joe' | 'driving' | 'USA' | 12:15 |
| 4 | 'joe' | 'driving' | 'USA' | 13:30 |
| 5 | 'joe' | 'at_store' | 'USA' | 15:00 |
| 5 | 'joe' | 'at_store' | 'USA' | 15:15 |
| 6 | 'joe' | 'driving' | 'USA' | 16:00 |
| 7 | 'joe' | 'driving' | 'USA' | 17:10 |
| 8 | 'joe' | 'at_home' | 'USA' | 20:00 |

In this table there can be three different status': "at_home", "at_store" and "driving".

I want a chronological order of movements by each person. For instance, for joe, this would look like at_home -> driving -> driving -> at_store -> at_store -> driving -> driving -> at_home

However, I want to remove any duplicate 'driving' status' and only keep the earliest. For instance, for joe, this would look like at_home -> driving -> at_store -> at_store -> driving -> at_home. I do not want to remove duplicate 'at_home' or 'at_store'

In this example, I want to keep the 'driving' status from 12:15 and keep the 'driving' status at 16:00 while removing the duplicate ones that follow.

I want to do this for each person specifically so when I do an 'order by time_updated', I can see all entries for that person in order.

If I query the resulting table using `"select * from db where name = 'joe' order by time_updated"`, my ideal result would be:

| serial(pk) | name | status | location | time_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'joe' | 'at_home' | 'USA' | 01:30 |
| 3 | 'joe' | 'driving' | 'USA' | 12:15 |
| 5 | 'joe' | 'at_store' | 'USA' | 15:00 |
| 5 | 'joe' | 'at_store' | 'USA' | 15:15 |
| 6 | 'joe' | 'driving' | 'USA' | 16:00 |
| 8 | 'joe' | 'at_home' | 'USA' | 20:00 |

Is there a way this can be done in postgres?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to delete contiguous rows with `status` = 'driving' (by `name`), you can exclude them from the result with this query (using `window function LAG()`):

```
WITH sq AS (SELECT *,
                   CASE WHEN status = 'driving' AND status = LAG(status) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_updated) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END contiguous_driving
            FROM t)
            
SELECT * 
FROM sq
WHERE name = 'joe' AND contiguous_driving = 0
ORDER BY time_updated;
```

If you still want to delete them, you can use the same subquery:

```
WITH sq AS (SELECT *,
                   CASE WHEN status = 'driving' AND status = LAG(status) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_updated) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END contiguous_driving
            FROM t)
            
DELETE FROM t
WHERE serial IN (SELECT serial
                 FROM sq 
                 WHERE contiguous_driving = 1);
```

**If `serial` column is the primary key, it cannot have duplicated values**.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a delete with exists logic:

```sql
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE status = 'driving' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.name = t1.name AND
                        t2.time_updated < t1.time_updated);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you get your results and order them by dates in reverse order to get the last row, you might even limit this search to a few of them or just the last one.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY time_updated DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Then if the status is 'driving'

```
UPDATE table SET time_updated = currenttime WHERE id = currentID
```

You might be able to do this automatically with triggers and procedures directly on postgres but that's beyond this question